# GKE Django MySQL is not accessible during rolling update

Tags: django, kubernetes, gcloud, google-cloud-sql, cloud-sql-proxy

I have Django application deployed in GKE. (Done with [this tutorial](https://cloud.google.com/python/django/kubernetes-engine))

My configuration file: **myapp.yaml**

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: myapp
  labels:
    app: myapp
spec:
  replicas: 3
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: myapp
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: myapp
    spec:
      containers:
      - name: myapp-app
        image: gcr.io/myproject/myapp
        imagePullPolicy: IfNotPresent

    ---------

      - image: gcr.io/cloudsql-docker/gce-proxy:1.16
        name: cloudsql-proxy
        command: ["/cloud_sql_proxy", "--dir=/cloudsql",
                  "-instances=myproject:europe-north1:myapp=tcp:3306",
                  "-credential_file=/secrets/cloudsql/credentials.json"]


apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: myapp
  labels:
    app: myapp
spec:
  type: LoadBalancer
  ports:
  - port: 80
    targetPort: 8080
  selector:
    app: myapp
```

**settings.py**

```
DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.mysql',
        'NAME': os.environ['DATABASE_NAME'],
        'USER': os.environ['DATABASE_USER'],
        'PASSWORD': os.environ['DATABASE_PASSWORD'],
        'HOST': '127.0.0.1',
        'PORT': os.getenv('DATABASE_PORT', '3306'),
    }
```

Now, when I do rolling update or via

```
kubectl rollout restart deployment myapp
```

or

```
kubectl apply -f myapp.yaml
```

`kubectl get pods` is in the following state:

```
NAME                         READY   STATUS        RESTARTS   AGE
myapp-8477898cff-5wztr   2/2     Terminating   0          88s
myapp-8477898cff-ndt5b   2/2     Terminating   0          85s
myapp-8477898cff-qxzsh   2/2     Terminating   0          82s
myapp-97d6ccfc4-4qmpj    2/2     Running       0          6s
myapp-97d6ccfc4-vr6mb    2/2     Running       0          4s
myapp-97d6ccfc4-xw294    2/2     Running       0          7s
```

I am getting the following error for some amount of time during rolling out:

```
OperationalError at /
(2003, "Can't connect to MySQL server on '127.0.0.1' (111)")
```

Please advise how can I ajust settings to have rollout without a downtime/this error

**UPD**

I have figured out by looking into logs that this happens because `cloudsql-proxy` brought down first while application container is still alive.

**Log of app**:

```
Found 3 pods, using pod/myapp-f59c686b5-6t7c4
[2022-02-27 17:39:55 +0000] [7] [INFO] Starting gunicorn 20.0.4
[2022-02-27 17:39:55 +0000] [7] [INFO] Listening at: http://0.0.0.0:8080 (7)
[2022-02-27 17:39:55 +0000] [7] [INFO] Using worker: sync
[2022-02-27 17:39:55 +0000] [10] [INFO] Booting worker with pid: 10
Internal Server Error: /api/health/    # here cloudsql-proxy died
Internal Server Error: /api/health/
Internal Server Error: /api/health/

.... here more messages of Internal Server Error ...

rpc error: code = NotFound desc = an error occurred when try to find container "ec7658770c772eff6efb544a502fcd1841d7401add6efb2b53bf264b8eca1bb6": not founde
```

**Log of cloudsql-proxy**

```
2022/02/28 08:17:58 New connection for "myapp:europe-north1:myapp"
2022/02/28 08:17:58 Client closed local connection on 127.0.0.1:3306
2022/02/28 08:17:58 Client closed local connection on 127.0.0.1:3306
2022/02/28 08:17:59 Received TERM signal. Waiting up to 0s before terminating.
```

So I guess solution should be to bring the order in shutdown - somehow shutdown the application **before** shutting down cloudsql-proxy when pod is updated.

Comment: Hi, Can you please share the complete logs?

Comment: @ZeenathSN, there actually nothing special in logs except that they show that app stops working since it lost SQL connection but still accepts the traffic which results in server error

Comment: Can you go through this [Github issue](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/cloudsql-proxy/issues/190) once, and let me know if it helps?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks like the sidecar for the proxy is terminating, and not letting you clean up before the application does.

Consider using the `-term-timeout` flag to give yourself some time: https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/cloudsql-proxy#-term_timeout30s

Comment: Set to one minute and that seems to help! Thanks!